# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Toggle not working (code pasted below)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I can't get the bootstrap toggle button to work on the browser, how can I identify the problem?

PS I have already added the Bootstrap CDN in my head tag and have added the jQuery and JavaScript in the body.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NAVBAR</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
      target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
      aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

remove `.navbar-expand-md` class to ALWAYS hide navbar links and display the toggler button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks alot!! it works :). If you dont mind me asking, what mistake did i make in my code?

Comment: I've downvoted this, as I think "try this code" is not very instructive. I shall be exceedingly happy to upvote or undownvote if an explanation can be added.

Comment: remove `.navbar-expand-md` class to ALWAYS hide navbar links and display the toggler button.

Answer (score 3):

The `id` attribute should not start with `#`. It should just be: `id="navbarSupportedContent"`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NAVBAR</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/xYH3DTrwlt

Comment: oh, my bad.. I did just remove the '#' but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: There's nothing else to do since I can't recreate the issue. Check your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js.

[popper.js.org](https://popper.js.org/)

This is written in the Bootstrap documentation)))

Comment: I did include popper.min.js

Answer (score 0):

```
data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
```

The `#` sign stands for the id.

The issue is here:

```
id="#navbarSupportedContent"
```

This should be

```
id="navbarSupportedContent"
```